# How to autofocus a Charfield in a Django ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, modelform

In my django app I want to set focus to the first CharField (task) when the page loads.

my **models.py** is

```
from django.db import models

class ListModel(models.Model):
    task = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.task} : {str(self.status)}"
```

and **forms.py** is

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import ListModel

class ListForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ListModel
        fields = ["task", "status"]
```

I have tried adding the following widget in my **CharField (in models.py)**:

```
task = models.CharField(max_length=255, widget=models.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': True})
```

but it gives an AttributeError: `module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'TextInput'`

I have also tried adding the following to the **ListForm class (in forms.py)**:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.fields['task'].widget.attrs.update(autofocus = 'autofocus')
```

though I am not getting any error for this, but when I load my page the focus is not set to the task CharField either. What can I do add auto-focus to my CharField?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing *model* fields (which are used to store data in the database), and *form* fields, which are used to obtain, validate and clean data the user has entered.

You thus work with:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from .models import ListModel

class ListForm(ModelForm):
    #  forms ↓
    task = forms.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        #  forms ↓
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': True})
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ListModel
        fields = ['task', 'status']
```